# How to center text inside a shape?

Tags: python, text, pygame, center

I want to display a number inside a circle.
The number must be centered (x,y).
How to do it?

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
screen= pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0))
black= (0,0,0)
white= (255,255,255)
red= (255,0,0)
number= "8"
bigfont = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 50)
text = bigfont.render(number, True, white)

def draw():
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (300,300), 200)
    screen.blit(text, (300,300))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 3):

Get the bounding rectangle of the text and set the center of the rectangle by the center of the text. Use the rectangle to `blit` the text:

```py
text_rect = text.get_rect()
text_rect.center = (300, 300)
screen.blit(text, text_rect)
```

The same with one line of code:

```py
screen.blit(text, text.get_rect(center = (300, 300)))
```

Use this code in a function:

```py
def draw_circle(x, y, text):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (x, y), 200)
    screen.blit(text, text.get_rect(center = (x, y)))
```

See [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit):

> [...] The dest argument can either be a pair of coordinates representing the position of the upper left corner of the blit or a *Rect*, where the upper left corner of the rectangle will be used as the position for the blit.

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
text = font.render("Text", True, (255, 255, 0))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False          

    window_center = window.get_rect().center

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 0, 0), window_center, 100)
    window.blit(text, text.get_rect(center = window_center))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: @HajpaHajpa This is exactly what my code does. In your the position of the circle is `(300, 300)` tis can be replace it by `(x, y)`. I've added a `draw_circle` function with the arguments (`x, y`)

Answer (score 0):

To centre PyGame text around point **x_pos, y_pos**:

1. Get the dimensions of the text object: `width, height = text.get_rect()[2:4]`
2. When you render (`screen.blit()`) the image, shift the coordinates back by half the width and half the height: `screen.blit(text, (x_pos - int(width / 2), y_pos - int(height / 2)))`